# Azure pipeline: do not build again in order to run tests

Tags: azure-devops

```
steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: 'Playtech.Neon.Privacy.TestPlaytech.Neon.Privacy.Test.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

I've noticed that the `test` step builds the solution again, which is stupid because
the solution has already been built by the build step so the tests should just use the `bin` directory that's already been made.

Can it do this? How?

Comment: Use the argument `--no-build` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dotnet commands like test or pack build the project by default.

There are 2 solutions to this:

1. Include the --no-build argument:

```
-task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: 'Playtech.Neon.Privacy.TestPlaytech.Neon.Privacy.Test.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

2. You can execute the tests on the .dll created by the build like so:

```
- script: dotnet test Playtech.Neon.Privacy.TestPlaytech.Neon.Privacy.Test.dll
  workingDirectory: '<Path_To_The_Build_Directory>'
  displayName: Run Tests
```

You can probably do the same with the DotNetCoreCLI@2 Task but I did not test that.

But overall reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#test) is always a good first step ;)